# почему во время второго Insert, id сходит с ума?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, autoincrement

```
CREATE TABLE `devices`.`common` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Department` INT NULL,
  `InvNumber` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Got` INT NULL,
  `WrittenOff` INT NULL,
  `Price` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

INSERT INTO devices.common (department,InvNumber,Name,Got,writtenoff,price)
    SELECT
    department,
    InvNumber,
    Name,
    Got,
    WrittenOff,
    Price
    FROM devices.main;


INSERT INTO devices.common (department,InvNumber,Name,Got,writtenoff,price)
    SELECT
    department,
    InvNumber,
    Name,
    Got,
    WrittenOff,
    Price
    FROM devices.cheap;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @talex проблема в том, что в поле id после 23 идет 32, а должно быть 24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) `AUTO_INCREMENT` гарантирует уникальность, но **не** гарантирует *непрерывность* в общем случае:

If the only statements executing are `“simple inserts”` where the number of rows to be inserted is known ahead of time, there are no gaps in the numbers generated for a single statement, except for `“mixed-mode inserts”`. **However, when `“bulk inserts”` are executed, there may be gaps in the auto-increment values assigned by any given statement.**

```
insert into table
select ... from ... another_table
```

можно рассматривать как `“bulk insert”`

Comment: я не совсем понял, как это исправить, можно немного конкретики?

Comment: Это врядли получится исправить используя `AUTO_INCREMENT`... Можно попробовать реализовать нечто подобное самому, но сделать это элегантно и производительно и чтобы нормально работало в многопользовательской среде - не так просто... PS учтите, например, случай когда транзакцию надо откатывать а параллельно с ней мы уже выдали следующий номер...